# Hybrid rendering bug?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

While using the official Blender 2.81 release for the first time (the last time I used Blender 2.81, it was still in Beta) I encountered a strange phenomenon while hybrid rendering in Cycles.

If I start a render with **only my CPU** enabled as a CUDA device my Ryzen 3600 chews through the 8100 tiles in about 3 minutes.

[image]

However if I additionally enable my GTX 970 and use **both in hybrid mode** my CPU seems to stand still not finishing a single tile.

[image]

The remaining time of 0.08 seconds is frozen as well, indicating that something is going horribly wrong. My system monitor is showing 100% CPU utilization, which is even more confusing to me. What is my CPU doing the entire time?

I have to mention, that I'm using Manjaro Linux and the AMD Catalyst driver-package has been discontinued recently, although that should only affect graphics cards not CPUs and my CPU has been rendering just fine on it's own.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just found out that this bug only occurs in the version of Blender that you get from the Manjaro repository. The binary from the official website seems to work fine. So I guess, I'll head over to a Manjaro forum and tell them about this...

Comment: There is no real reason to use the versions in repositories, usually they are not well maintained. Blender in Linux doesn't need to be "installed".

Comment: I know, but I personally like to get all my software via pacman/trizen if possible, because it means virtually no maintenance work for me. And if I don't install via this method, KDE won't show Blender under my list of applications.